# TI WL1897, which board and battery fits

Tags: bluetooth

I have seen the TI WL1897 (No Data page available) at a glance it looks good for many Low Power projects. Which battery and board fit it best?  Is there a Developer kit? I would like to put it on the smallest board possible.

Comment: You should give an application and some requirements, otherwise is like shooting in the air waiting for a bird to pass by.

Comment: You must be a "top-tier OEM" to get access to WiLink 8 parts.  If that doesn't describe you, wait for the next generation of mobile phones to come out for Christmas 2012 and choose one for your development platform.

Comment: The application is on iOS/android the space is limited 40 X 40 mm X 8 mm (w X l X h ). power should be via coin battery.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, the WL1897 is no longer being offered by TI. It didn't go into sampling until Feb 2013, and in the interim, the NFC capable WiLink8 modules WL189x have been quietly phased out. Given your requirements for power saving bluetooth in 40 x 40 x 8 mm ,  The TI Simple Link CC2xxx line would be good. It has multiple dev kits, would fit in that space without issue, and is meant for coin cell usage.